# Targeting an active link in CSS

Tags: asp.net, html, css, asp.net-mvc-3

I wrote a custom HtmlHelper to apply...

```
class = "active"
```

to a menu item if that is the current page.  After viewing the source, I know that this is working correctly, but within my current set-up, I can't seem to target the .active class to apply any styles to it.

**Current HTML**

```
<ul id="menu">
    <li>@Html.MenuItem("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
    <li>@Html.MenuItem("About", "About", "Home")</li>
</ul>
```

**Current CSS**

```
#menu { width: 100%;
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
      list-style-type: none;
      padding-top: 6px; }

#menu a { width: 100%;
            font-weight: bold;
            text-decoration: none;
            color: #ffffff;
            padding: 6px 8px 6px 8px;
            text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #8292a2; }

#menu a:hover { background-color: #e8eff6; color: #2a3744; text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #e8eff6; }

#menu li { display: inline; }
```

I am assuming I have a specificity issue going on here, but I can't seem to target the "active" class to apply any type of style to it.

```
#menu a.active
#menu li a.active
```

Nothing seems to work.  Any ideas?

**EDIT:**
custom HtmlHelper I am using

```
public static class MenuExtensions
    {
        public static MvcHtmlString MenuItem(
            this HtmlHelper htmlHelper,
            string text,
            string action,
            string controller
        )
        {
            string value;
            var routeData = htmlHelper.ViewContext.RouteData;
            var currentAction = routeData.GetRequiredString("action");
            var currentController = routeData.GetRequiredString("controller");
            if (string.Equals(currentAction, action, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) &&
                string.Equals(currentController, controller, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            {
                value = htmlHelper.ActionLink(text, action, new { controller = controller }, new { @class = "active" }).ToHtmlString();
                return MvcHtmlString.Create(value.ToString());
            }

            value = htmlHelper.ActionLink(text, action, controller).ToHtmlString();
            return MvcHtmlString.Create(value.ToString());
        }
    }
```

HTML output by viewing source

```
<ul id="menu">
   <li><a class="active" href="/">Home</a></li>
   <li><a href="/Home/About">About</a></li>
</ul>
```

As I've said, I know it is working, I just can't seem to target the "active" class even though it exists...

Comment: What does the output html look like?

Comment: <ul id="menu"><li><a class="active" href="/">Home</a></li><li><a href="/Home/About">About</a></li></ul>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you put a.active, you should use the ":" like you did with hover. `a:active`

Edit: after re-reading your question, did you mean a custom css class for menu-items that link to the page the user is currently on? In that case, the way I use ASP, it will automatically take care of those menu items for you. Otherwise, I don't see where you assign that class to your menu items? That is a first problem for sure.

Comment: This isn't what I am looking for.    a:active only works with links once clicked.  I could call my "active" anything I wanted really, I just chose that.  I have a C# class that creates a link    <a class="active" href"/" /> if it is the current page (based on routeData).  So suppose I call it "currentPage"... how do I get it to work?

Comment: Like I noticed in my edit, I don't see where you're adding that custom class to your menu item? I'm used to work with ASP without MVC though..

Comment: It's added via a custom HtmlHelper which I supppose is specific to MVC.  Basically it looks at the routeData and is able to pick apart the URL based on controllers and actions (MVC specific) and output html in its placed.  So in my example, it is taking in the text (Home), action (index), and controller (home)... that happens to be the homepage of the website, so it adds a link element in html as follows... <a class="active" href="/">Home</a>  I just can't seem to target that class?

Comment: Can you show the specific ASP code that adds the link to the html? Also have you verified that it is actually in the output html by inspecting the source in your browser?

Comment: I added both to the original post

Comment: It's just a guess, but since there is nothing essentially wrong with the code... It could be that since "active" is defined as a pseudo-class in css, your name could be the very reason it doesn't work. Does it work when you take another name, like you suggested "currentPage"?

Comment: I hate my life.  Thank you... I actually tried "current" after that and realized that wouldn't really be any wiser... then went with "currentPage" and it works like a charm... Thanks for pointing that one out :)